# Dynamically generate {!Community_Url}

Tags: apex, community

Is it possible to generate {!Community_Url} dynamically in the apex and then pass it on to VF email template?
Does the link created programatically have the encrypted key to take the user to the password set screen and log them to the community?

Comment: Does the link take the user to the password set page?

Comment: It will give you login URL then you can make the password change URL.

Comment: How will this link know about the context of the external user?

Comment: I do not think it is the same question being answered. I need a URL which is unique to a user and not a base URL which is common to everyone. I want the value for this field $Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails. I am creating a new question.